# Cypress test failing - Nextjs's router.back() not redirecting after login on CircleCI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress, circleci

I'm having some trouble debugging Cypress test errors in CircleCI. These work locally. The tests are against a react web app's login page, which after a successful login will call `router.back()` from Nextjs's `next/router` to go back to the previous page. This works fine locally as well as the functionality working on the actual website, but in the cypress tests, the page does not redirect back, but stays on the login page.

Here is the test's before each with the router:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   cy.visit("/login");
   cy.intercept("OPTIONS", "*", {
      statusCode: 200,
   });
   cy.intercept("POST", "/login*", {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: { message: "Login successful" },
   }).as("loginRequest");
});
```

And here is the test:

```
const testEmail = "test@email.com";
const testPassword = "TestPassword123";

cy.visit("/articles/what-is-spirituality");
cy.visit("/login");

cy.findByRole("textbox", { name: "Email address" }).type(testEmail);

cy.get('[id="password-id"]').type(testPassword);
cy.get("button").contains("Log In").click();

// all three of these calls fail
cy.get("button").contains("Log In").should("not.exist");
cy.url().should("not.include", "/login");
cy.url().should("include", "/articles/what-is-spirituality");
```

If I make two calls to `cy.window().its("history").invoke("back");` I can get the test working, so the page history is available, it's just that the redirect is failing.

We have tried waits, both waiting on the intercept `cy.wait("@loginRequest");` and waiting for 10 seconds `cy.wait(10000);` and neither of these worked.